# passing variable in TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm new in Tkinter and trying to create a " brows button" when you click on, you choose an image, and the path of the image should be saved and then pass the path of the image to another function
I try this but I got `NameError: name 'MI' is not defined`

I want to pass `MI`(which is the path of the chosen photo ) to the `blur()` function could you help me?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog
import cv2 as cv

color = '#20536C'
root = Tk()
root.title('main page')
root.configure(bg=color)
root.geometry('1070x700')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

# =================================== Frames ===================================

top = Frame(root, width=1070, height=70, bg='yellow')
top.pack(side=TOP)
# top.grid(row = 0 , column= 1)
left = Frame(root, width=750, height=630, bg='#20536C')
left.pack(side=LEFT)
# left.grid(row = 1 , column= 1)
right = Frame(root, width=320, height=630, bg="red")
right.pack(side=LEFT)

# =================================== Buttons ===================================

btnBrowse = Button(top, width=93, text='select file', font=('Times', 15, 'italic', 'bold')
                   , command=lambda: open_image())
btnBrowse.pack(side=BOTTOM)

btnMask = Button(right, text='show', width=19, height=6,
                 command=lambda: blur(MI))
btnMask.pack(side=TOP)

btnMakula = Button(right, text='M', width=19, height=6)
btnMakula.pack(side=TOP)

btnClear = Button(right, text='exit', width=19, height=6, command=root.quit)
btnClear.pack(side=TOP)
# =================================== Text =====================================

textBox = Text(left, width=90, height=10, )
textBox.place(x=20, y=455)


# =================================== Functions ===================================

def open_image():
    global mainImage ,MI
    '''      file dialog way      '''
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="J://uni//final project//thired phase",
                                               title="select an image",
                                               filetypes=(('jpg files', '*.jpg'), ('all files', '*.*'))
                                               )
    MI = root.filename
    mainImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
    img = Label(left, image=mainImage).place(x=20, y=0)
    imageBox = Label(left, text=root.filename, width=65, height=20, bd=3).place(x=20, y=0)

    ''' actually, it's not opening the file it's bringing the location of the file
        then we can open the choosen file via location'''

    # label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
    return MI

def blur(MI):
    I = cv.imread(MI)
    I2 = cv.blur(I,3)
    cv.imshow('dfdf1',I)
    cv.waitKey()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As long as you have selected a file in `open_image()` via `select file` button, you should not get the mentioned error.  However you will get another error on calling `cv.blur()`.

Comment: Would appreciate marking the answer as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

While python is executing the code and reaches the line

```
btnMask = Button(right, text='show', width=19, height=6,
                 command=lambda: blur(MI))
```

It checks for `MI` but `MI` doesn't exist, during the execution of this line and hence the error. `MI` is not defined as long as `open_image()` is read by python. You dont have to pass `MI` as an argument, making it global at `open_image()` should make it available to use at `blur()`.

```
btnMask = Button(right, text='show', width=19, height=6,
                 command=blur)
.... #same code as yours

def blur():
    I = cv.imread(MI)
    I2 = cv.blur(I,3)
    cv.imshow('dfdf1',I)
    cv.waitKey()
```

Also its safe to remove `lambda` if your not passing in any arguments. So that would make your buttons:

```
btnBrowse = Button(top, width=93, text='select file', font=('Times', 15, 'italic', 'bold'), command=open_image)

btnMask = Button(right, text='show', width=19, height=6,
                 command=blur)
```

So basically your error is related to misunderstanding with the direction of flow of code.

Not sure if this gonna fix all your errors. Do let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

If `MI` is global, try to use:

```
btnMask = Button(right, text='show', width=19, height=6,
                 command=lambda: blur())
```

and:

```
def blur():
    ....
```

with out **`MI`**